# Minimize the $f(t)=\sqrt{(-bt-a/c-x_0)^2 +(at-y_0)^2}$ function

Tags: calculus

I think I knew how to do it but algebraically. But I got some issues and might got a bug with the sympy package. Could you help me to verify the algebra, please?

To minimize $f(t)=\sqrt{(-bt-a/c-x_0)^2 +(at-y_0)^2}$

First, $$f'(t)=0\Rightarrow \frac{a \left(a t - y_{0}\right) - b \left(- \frac{a}{c} - b t - x_{0}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(a t - y_{0}\right)^{2} + \left(- \frac{a}{c} - b t - x_{0}\right)^{2}}} =0$$

This indicated $$t_0=\frac{- a b + a c y_{0} - b c x_{0}}{c \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)}$$.

However, when I tried to substitute $t_0$ into $f(t)$

$$f(t_0)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{a \left(- a b + a c y_{0} - b c x_{0}\right)}{c \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)} - y_{0}\right)^{2} + \left(- \frac{a}{c} - \frac{b \left(- a b + a c y_{0} - b c x_{0}\right)}{c \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)} - x_{0}\right)^{2}}$$.

The numerator contained a six order polynomial in $a$,
$$\left(a^{2} b + a b c x_{0} + b^{2} c y_{0}\right)^{2} + \left(a^{3} + a^{2} c x_{0} + 2 a b^{2} - a b c y_{0} + 2 b^{2} c x_{0}\right)^{2}$$
and the result was
$$c^{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{c^{6} \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)^{4}}} \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right) \sqrt{\left(a \left(a b - a c y_{0} + b c x_{0}\right) + c y_{0} \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)\right)^{2} + \left(a \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right) - b \left(a b - a c y_{0} + b c x_{0}\right) + c x_{0} \left(a^{2} + b^{2}\right)\right)^{2}}$$

(This was directly output by sympy's simplification with assumption that $a,b,c,x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$, obviously it had issues.)

But the result ought to be

$$f(t_0)=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Could you help me to check which part went wrong with the calculation, please? It's supposed to be very straight forward minimization, find $f'(t_0)=0$ and then find $f(t_0)$, but I couldn't figure out what went wrong, neither did sympy and wolfram alpha.

Comment: Avoid the complexity by maximizing $[f(t)]^2$ instead.

Comment: In the second square root, $a^2cy_0$ cancels out in the first parenthesis, and $ab^2+b^2cx_0$ cancels out in the second parenthesis. Also, the second factor $a^2+b^2$ cancels out $(a^2+b^2)^2$ in the denominator of the first square root. Now check what's left, maybe you can simplify it further.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein $(a*x_0+b*y_0+c)^2=a^{2} x_{0}^{2} + 2 a b x_{0} y_{0} + 2 a c x_{0} + b^{2} y_{0}^{2} + 2 b c y_{0} + c^{2}$. But the output result squared multiply by $(a^2+b^2)$ was $\frac{a^{4}}{c^{2}} + \frac{2 a^{3} x_{0}}{c} + \frac{2 a^{2} b y_{0}}{c} + a^{2} x_{0}^{2} + 2 a b x_{0} y_{0} + b^{2} y_{0}^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A slightly simpler way then doing all the derivation and calculus is to analyze $[f(t)]^2$ properties.

Lets look at the function $$g(t) = \sqrt{\color\violet{t^2} \cdot u + \color\violet{t} \cdot v + s}$$, where $ut^2 + vt + s > 0$.

As suggested by @coffeemath, anaylsing the quadratic enables us to find out that minimum is at the vertex at $-v/2u$. Note that square root is applied last and does not affect the $t_{min}$ of quadratic. Consequently, $g(-v/2u) = \sqrt{\frac{4us - v^2}{4u}}$

Now, observe that $$\sqrt{\underbrace{\left(-bt - a/c - x_0\right)^2}_{\color{green}{\Large+}} + \underbrace{\left(at - y_0\right)^2}_{\color{green}{\Large+}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\color\violet{t^2}\cdot(a^2 + b^2)\cdot c^2 + \color\violet{t} \cdot 2c \cdot (bcx_0 - acy_0 + ab) + c^2x_0^2 + 2acx_0 + c^2y_0^2+a^2}{c^2}}$$

So, we substitute,

$u = a^2 + b^2$

$v = 2(b(x_0+a/c) - ay_0)$

$s = x_0^2 + 2ax_0/c + (a/c)^2 + y_0^2 = (x_0 + a/c)^2 + y_0^2$

$$f\left(\frac{-2(bx_0-ay_0+ab/c)}{2(a^2 + b^2)}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{4(a^2 + b^2)((x_0 + a/c)^2 + y_0^2) - 4(b(x_0+a/c) - ay_0)^2}{4(a^2 + b^2)}}
\\= \sqrt{\frac{a^2(x_0 + a/c)^2 + b^2y_0^2 + 2aby_0(x_0+a/c)}{a^2 + b^2}}
\\= \sqrt{\frac{(a(x_0 + a/c) + by_0)^2}{a^2 + b^2}}
\\= \sqrt{\frac{(acx_0 + a^2 + bcy_0)^2}{c^2(a^2 + b^2)}}
\\= \frac{|acx_0 + bcy_0 + a^2|}{|c|\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Reduce CAS (an elder version that still works on my dated x86) returns for $t$ the same as you got. Substitution in first equation results in
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}}\mathrm{abs}\left(a^2+acx_{0}+bcy_{0}\right)}{\mathrm{abs}\left(c\right)}$$
what is not too far away from what you show as *correct* result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to minimize the distance from the line $ax+by+c=0$ to the point $(x_0,y_0)$. In that case, the first parenthesis in $f(t)$ **should have $c/a$, not $a/c$**. Then
$$
a\left(bt-\frac{c}{a}\right)+b\left(at\right)+c=abt-c+bat+c=0.
$$
Then,
$$
a\left(a t_0 - y_{0}\right) - b \left(- \frac{c}{a} - b t_0 - x_{0}\right)=0,
$$
i.e.
$$
t_0=\frac{ay_0-bx_0-\frac{bc}{a}}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{-bax_0+a^2y_0-bc}{a(a^2+b^2)}
$$
Then
$$
at_0-y_0=\frac{-bax_0+a^2y_0-bc}{a^2+b^2}-y_0=\frac{-bax_0-b^2y_0-bc}{a^2+b^2}=-\frac{b(ax_0+by_0+c)}{a^2+b^2},
$$
so
$$
-bt_0-x_0-\frac{c}{a}=-\frac{a}{b}(at_0-y_0)=\frac{a(ax_0+by_0+c)}{a^2+b^2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
f(t_0)&=\sqrt{\left(-bt_0-x_0-\frac{c}{a}\right)^2+\left(at_0-y_0\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(a\cdot\frac{ax_0+by_0+c}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(-b\cdot\frac{ax_0+by_0+c}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+c\right|}{a^2+b^2}\cdot\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+c\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},
\end{split}
$$
as desired.